# Databricks: How do I get path of current notebook?

Tags: path, jupyter-notebook, databricks, azure-databricks

Databricks is smart and all, but how do you identify the path of your current notebook? The guide on the [website](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/faq/get-notebook-path.html) does not help.

It suggests:

```
%scala
dbutils.notebook.getContext.notebookPath
res1: Option[String] = Some(/Users/user@org.dk/my_test_notebook)
```

This does not give me the complete path, but rather the path to some folder structure that is not accessible from the notebook. I need the path, such that I can make system calls in the same folder as the **.ipynb** file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Access file using Databricks API

I ended up somewhat resolving the problem using the Databricks API to download and upload notebooks and other files to/from Databricks.

### 1. Read documentation for Databricks Workspace API

[Databricks API Documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace.html)

### 2. Generate API token and Get Notebook path

In the user interface do the following to generate an API Token and copy notebook path:

1. Choose 'User Settings'
2. Choose 'Generate New Token'
3. In Databrick file explorer, "right click" and choose "Copy File Path"

### 3. Download a Notebook from Databricks

If you want to access a notebook file, you can download it using a curl-call. If you are located inside a Databricks notebook, you can simply make this call either using cell magic, %sh, or using a system call, os.system('insert command').

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request GET --data '{"path":"{/Users/myuser@myorg.com/notebook_to_download}","format":"JUPYTER"}' https://{replace_with_your_databaricks}/api/2.0/workspace/export -H "Authorization: Bearer {my_token}" | jq -r .content | base64 --decode > my_downloaded_notebook.ipynb
```

### 4. Uploading a Notebook to Databricks

You can similarly upload a notebook from a machine using the following curl call:

```
curl -n -F format=JUPYTER -F path="{/Users/myuser@myorg.com/uploaded_notebook}" -F language=PYTHON -F content=@{/my/local/notebook.ipynb} https://{replace_with_your_databaricks}/api/2.0/workspace/import -H "Authorization: Bearer {my_token}"
```

Comment: Hi Esben, I am trying to execute the import curl inside Jenkins pipeline which is getting executed in a Linux machine. Could you please let me know the path

sh """
                curl -n -F format=SOURCE -F path="/Users/anupam@domain.com/notebook_file.py" -F language=PYTHON -F content=@notebook_file.py https://test-dev.cloud.databricks.com/api/2.0/workspace/import -H "Authorization: Bearer token"
               """

Comment: It sounds like you are doing a nested call. Usually it is something like: sh -c 'write your command in here'. Example NOT working: sh """curl""", Example working: sh -c """curl"""

Answer (score 34):

You can retrieve the information by using dbutils command:

```
dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().notebookPath().get()
```

Comment: Where did you find the documentation for this function?

Comment: As far as I understood, this command is applicable for Python.
For Scala it's:
dbutils.notebook().getContext().notebookPath.get

Comment: It gives me an error `AttributeError: module 'dbutils' has no attribute 'notebook'`

Answer (score 14):

For Scala it's:

```
dbutils.notebook().getContext().notebookPath.get
```

For Python:

```
dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().notebookPath().get()
```

Comment: In Python it gives me an error `AttributeError: module 'dbutils' has no attribute 'notebook'`

Comment: Sorry Vladimir, cannot help you with that. The code works for me.

Comment: This python simply gives the base notebeook path alone , Lets say there notebook_a and it calls the notebook_b, if you run notebook_a and try to print the dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().notebookPath().get() inside notebook_b , then it shows the notebook_a .

Answer (score 3):

Notebook doesn't stay on the driver. Whenever you run a cell that cell will be sent for execution in the current spark session.

Try this to check.

```
%sh
pwd
ls
```

If you want to access some files or code you can upload it [DBFS](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/dbfs-databricks-file-system.html) and access it. If it is code, you can compile it to a .jar(java, Scala) or an .egg(python) and attach the [library](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/libraries.html) to the cluster on which you are running the notebook.

Comment: The issue is that Databricks does not have integration with VSTS. A workaround is to download the notebook locally using the CLI and then use git locally. I would, however, prefer to keep everything in Databricks. If I can download the .ipynb to the dbfs, then I can use a system call to push the notebooks to VSTS using git.

Comment: @EsbenEickhardt: As of January 2019, Databricks now has VSTS (now called Azure DevOps) integration.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the path of the notebook through this steps and the answers is in the suggestions of your question also . (Assuming that the notebook you are working on is yours)

1. Go to the workspace
2. If the notebook is in particular user folder . Click on Users
3. Click on particular user@org.dk
4. Then on the notebook name /my_test_notebook

so your final path becomes /Users/user@org.dk/my_test_notebook

Comment: Author is asking about another thing - he was able to get path via `dbutils.notebook.getContext.notebookPath` call...